# Coming back on a page with the same quicktab and fields expanded (items do not remain expanded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, field, expandable

I have a website with Drupal 7. On one page, we have two quicktabs (using quicktabs module), under each quicktab we have expendable fields. Those fields are expandables thanks to this code:

```
jQuery(".ideas-content").hide();
jQuery(".ideas-title").click(function () {
jQuery(this).toggleClass('ideas-closed').toggleClass('ideas-open').next(".ideas-content").toggle();
});
```

The user can click links inside these expandable fields to go to another inside page. When the user goes to the previous page (the page with these expandable fields), quicktabs are back to default and the fields the user previously expanded are not expanded anymore.

How can I do to have the user coming back on the page with the right quicktab and fields expanded? I was thinking to create anchor links but I do not know more.

I googled the issue with no success.

Thank you for any input and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to access the exact HTML of your page, through template.php function overrides, .tpl.php overrides, or by writing the HTML yourself within the page.tpl, you can add IDs and classes around the elements you want, and then since you are using javascript, you can try using a library such as https://github.com/browserstate/history.js in order to get functionality to take the user back to the state they were in -- with open sections -- after going to another page.